# How to configure DHCP server on two interfaces with same Subnet mask

Tags: freebsd, dhcp

I am using FreeBSD server 10.1. I have 3 Interfaces re0, re1, wlan0. I attached the Internet cable on re0 and configure dhcpd_iface as wlan0.
so that any devices that are connecting with my wifi can get the IP address. Now I want any devices that is trying to connect with re1 get the IP address of same subnet mask as of wifi.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to bridge wlan0 and re1 and run dhcpd on the bridge interface.  Something like this:

```
cloned_interfaces="bridge0"
ifconfig_bridge0="addm re1 addm wlan0 up"
ifconfig_bridge0_alias0="inet 192.168.0.1/24"
```

That'll create a `bridge0` interface bridging `wlan0` and `re1` together.  Now you can run your DHCP server on the `bridge0` interface.